# Rigify new face rig blender 3.0

Tags: rigging, add-on, rigify

There's a new version of rigify, that's awesome, problem being it fails at generating the rig with this error:

```
RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'jaw_master': Mouth corner counts differ: ['lip_end.B.L.001'] vs [] Incorrect armature for type 'skin_jaw'
```

After meddling a bit with it I figured the problem was about the placement of the `jaw_master`, but I don't understand how it has to be placed in order to avoid this.

Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 2):

First solution I found:
upgrade the face rig BEFORE setting your rig, I wouldn't recommend you to delete one side of the meta-rig to symetrize it later, just use the mirror and place the bones...